# Why can we not delete questions which have two answers with negative scores?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

This is super weird to me, just because the message is "People have put time and effort into answering this question..." but that justification doesn't work for questions with one answer without upvotes, so why should it work for questions with multiple answers without upvotes (or with downvotes)?

Note: this isn't about a specific question or a question of mine, I'm just curious.

Comment: One factor is the ability of the OP to downvote and using that to make a question deletable.  For example, if you are permit the OP to delete a post that has 2 negatively scored answers, and you have a post that received 2 seperate answers (with zero score), the OP could quickly downvote and delete the post.

Comment: @psubsee2003 most self deletions I've seen are from relatively new users that haven't yet gotten downvote privs. I think the rationale is more along the lines of if there's two or more answers then there's an indication the question posed is answerable and attempts are being made... Even if they don't get upvoted until further clarification/they're improved upon to receive a vote, then the OP shouldn't be able to self-delete and potentially stop that from happening.

Comment: Plus... if you've received a downvote on your answer, work out what you've done wrong and are willing to fix it to get upvotes, it'd be frustrating if the OP was able to nuke the question while you were working on fixing your answer...

Comment: @JonClements I don't doubt that that's the rational, but I don't think it's correct.  People repeatedly show a willingness to post answers to bad questions, even unanswerable questions.  Unsurprisingly, these answers tend to not be useful, and so they aren't worth preventing the deletion of the question.

Comment: @Servy The question isn't prevented from being deleted completely - just deleted unilaterally by the asker and since it's getting answers then presumably it's getting views and is currently active. Which means the question could be closed, answers receive further downvotes (maybe prompting the answerer to self-delete) or comments/suggestions to clarify the question/answers... At that point, it could be considered unfair to have the asker have unilateral powers to remove the whole lot of that activity...

Comment: @JonClements In my experiences moderators tend to be rather wary of deleting bad questions with multiple bad answers, stating most of the rational you're giving now, so I would consider other paths of deletion particularly practical.  That a question has two answers doesn't mean it's active; the answers could be a year old, with zero views in the past six months (and only a dozen total).  Additionally, if any of the answerers feel that the post *is* valuable, and they want the information to stay public, they can simply re-post the question and their answer under their own name.

Comment: @Servy I'm talking more about the "hit'n'run" perspective and the "I've got an answer great, oh - now I've got another answer with another solution - I'll delete my question"... For older "train wrecks" of Q/A's I'd hope the roomba would clear out the majority of those and the rest can always be closed (if not already) and community deleted if discovered in the wild.

Comment: @JonClements If people are asking good questions and getting good answers, then the answers wouldn't be likely to have a negative score.  As for community deletion, that takes a *lot* of work from a *lot* of people, with a high level of privilege, typically over an extended period of time.  As a result, "pretty bad" posts don't really have a shot at community deletion, even if there's nothing of value in the post; it takes *egregiously* bad posts to get enough attention from enough people over a long enough period of time to get deleted.

Comment: @JonClements I'd also like to point out that those "hit and run" type questions that this rule is in place to prevent also tend to be of fairly low quality, on average.  A huge percentage of them are questions that *wouldn't* actually be of value to other people, so we *don't* have any reason to keep them around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148904/discussion-between-jon-clements-and-servy).

Answer (score 2):

As Jon said in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352047/why-can-we-not-delete-questions-which-have-two-answers-with-negative-scores#comment491336_352047) the reason for not allowing the asker to delete questions with multiple answers is that more than one person has responded so the question is classed as being more active than one with no answers or only one answer.

The rules could be extended to allow this, but I suspect the cases where all the answers are down-voted are so rare it's probably not worth the effort.